# Getting back a date from a string

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

im dealing with dates, and i'm having problems getting my date back from a string, i simplified my problem here:

```
let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY"
formatter.stringFromDate(date)
formatter.dateFromString(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
```

And the output is:
"25-05-2015" (Which is fine)
"Dec 21, 2014, 12:00 AM" (???)

Comment: The output of what? The code you posted doesn't store or log any strings or dates.

Comment: @maddy, the 4th line return `25-05-2015` and the last return `2014-12-21 05:00:00 +0000` for me.

Comment: @rmaddy Probably using Swift playground and talking about the "output" in the right-hand margin. http://i.imgur.com/LDaBYH4.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem there is that `Y` is for `weekOfYear`. You have to use `"dd-MM-yyyy"`. Btw don't forget to [set your date formatter locale to "en_US_POSIX"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html) .

> If you're working with fixed-format dates, you
>   should first set the locale of the date formatter to something
>   appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to
>   choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to
>   yield US English results regardless of both user and system
>   preferences. "en_US_POSIX" is also invariant in time (if the US, at
>   some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, "en_US"
>   will change to reflect the new behaviour, but "en_US_POSIX" will not),
>   and between machines ("en_US_POSIX" works the same on iOS as it does
>   on OS X, and as it it does on other platforms).

Answer (score 2):

You should use  `yyyy` for the year, not `YYYY` (which has a different meaning)

```
let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

let s = formatter.stringFromDate(date) // "25-05-2015"
let d = formatter.dateFromString(s)    // "2015-05-24 22:00:00 UTC" (*)
```

*(*) it's 22:00 because I'm in the +0200 timezone, so this result is effectively 2015-05-25 00:00:00 in my timezone*

Answer (score 0):

You should change your dateFormat to make it work , YYYY is not correct.

```
import Foundation

let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY"
var firstDate = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSxxx"
var secondDate = formatter.dateFromString(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
println("\(firstDate)")
println("\(secondDate)")
```